# Limit and behavior of function around $0$

Tags: limits

A question that I was stuck on said that if we have, 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$$ Then which one of the following is necessarily true, 
$$\text{a})\; f(0) = 0 $$
$$\text {b}) \lim _{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$$

I saw this question and immediately thought of the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$  but $\sin x$ satisfies both the conditions so that isn't really much help. Any thoughts since I can't think of anything else, I have tried everything including L'Hopital.

Comment: Consider:  $f$ is not necessarily continuous at $0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner but if it isn't continuous at $0$ then how are we defining a limit in the first place, wouldn't LHL $\neq$ RHL?

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous, it would be possible to have $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ but $f(x)=3$ for example [you could define $f(x)=\sin(x)$ when $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=3$, for example]

Comment: @J.W.Tanner As an off-topic comment: You've edited $>2100$ posts? That's impressive

Comment: Yes, thanks, @MaximilianJanisch, I got a gold badge after $500$

Comment: Note that [Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/202857/bernard) has edited > $8000$

Comment: A limit as $x\to a$ does not tell anything about $x=a$ so your first option a) is false. Option b) is true and you can use limit laws on $f(x) =\dfrac{f(x)} {x} \cdot x$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ok I just noticed that [Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11667/michael-hardy?tab=topactivity) has edited over 25000 posts... How does that even work? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**b)** is true since otherwise we would have some sequence $x_n$ going to $0$ such that $|f(x_n)|\geq \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ so that $f(x_n)\over x_n$ would not converge to $0$.

**a)** doesn't have to be true since the value of $f$ at $0$ doesn't matter. If $f$ is continuous and defined at $0$, then a) must be true as well of course.

---

**Edit:** Some intuition (to be more precise, I will assume that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$):

*About a):* The limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}x$ **does not depend** on the value of $f$ at $0$ by the definition of a limit. So there is no way to conclude a).
*About b):* If $f$ doesn't converge to $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$, then $f$ "stays away" from $0$ in infinitely many points close to $0$. In these points, $\frac{f(x)}x$ will be arbitrarily far from $0$ once $x$ is close enough to $0$. In that case, $\frac{f(x)}x$ can't converge to $0$ as $x\to 0$. It follows that b) must be true by argument from contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is not very vlear to me could you perhaps explain it a little less mathematically and maybe more intuitively. Or just edit the math a little so I can understand it better.

Comment: @PrakharNagpal I've added some intuition to my answer